# convergence of a series using the root test

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I want to find whether this series diverges or converges using the root test
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \arccos^n \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)  $$
$$ \sqrt[n] {\arccos^n \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}  $$
$$  \arccos \sqrt[n] {\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}  $$
$$  \arccos  1 = 0  $$
and since its 0 the series should converge but I am not sure about the calculations there.

Comment: The third line is wrong.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't know how to contact you in a polite way. Raffaele's hypothesis is false :( so I deleted my answer. $341, 561, 645$ are counterexamples in the first thousand...

Comment: $\arccos\frac{1}{n^2}\to 1$

Comment: I still dont understand fully how is arcos 1/n^2 equal to one if we take the limit

Comment: @GregoryStory16. $\frac \pi 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series diverges. Indeed
$$\arccos^n\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\sim \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^n+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right);\;n\to\infty$$
The first $50$ terms sum is about $1.7\times 10^{10}$.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that

$$\arccos(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin(x) =\frac{\pi}{2}-x+O(x^2) \to \frac \pi 2 $$

therefore the series diverges since $a_n \not \to 0$.